# Loop Two Query Arrays and ECHO in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, echo

```
$query = "
 SELECT SUM(KDV_Haric_Ciro) AS Ciro , Donem
                    FROM general_Table
                    Where EczaneID = '".$pharmacy_id."' AND Yil = '".$dateYear."'
                    GROUP BY Donem";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query );

$queryTwo = "
 SELECT SUM(KDV_Haric_Ciro) AS Ciro, Donem
                    FROM general_Table
                    Where EczaneID = '".$pharmacy_id."' AND Yil = '".$dateLastYear."'
                    GROUP BY Donem";
$resultTwo = mysqli_query($link, $queryTwo );

// Print out rows
$prefix = '';
echo "[\n";
while ( ??? //$rowTwo = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $resultTwo ) -> loops through only 1 array
) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $resultTwo )
  echo $prefix . " {\n";
  echo '  "month": "' . $rowTwo["Donem"] . '",' . "\n";
  echo '  "ciro": ' . $row["Ciro"]. '' . "\n";
  echo '  "ciroLastYear": ' . $rowTwo["Ciro"]. '' . "\n";
  echo " }";
  $prefix = ",\n";
}
echo "\n]";
```

so basically im fetchind data in json for another api but i need to echo two data in same loop i have tried a lot of things can you fill while(???) part so that i can

Comment: You need to merge your two result sets into one set and then loop through that, or better yet write one query that will return the result you expect, without having to deal with two result sets.

Comment: Why would you have two same queries?

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about rewriting the SQL so you pull the data in one pull?

```
SELECT donem,
       SUM(CASE WHEN yil IN ('2016') then kdv_haric_ciro) AS prior_year,
       SUM(CASE WHEN yil IN ('2017') then kdv_haric_ciro) AS current_year       
  FROM general_table
 WHERE eczaneid = '".$pharmacy_id."'
 GROUP BY donem
```

Now you don't have to loop through two different queries you only have to loop through one result set and format it for your API call.

Comment: sql doesnt work can you make a working sql? i dont know how to use sum case, please?

Comment: I made some assumptions on what the data was when I made that. I can make it work if you could post what the data looks like. I assumed Yil was a date column I could extract the year from. I also assumed the kdv_haric_ciro was the value you wanted summed.

Comment: yil is an char, kdv_haric_ciro is double

Comment: If Yil is not a date field then I don't think this will work. If you could post a couple of rows of sample data it would help.

Comment: pharmacy_id:101
Donem:4
Yıl:2016
KDV_Haric_Ciro:20.98
-------------
pharmacy_id:101
Donem:3
Yıl:2017
KDV_Haric_Ciro:165.23

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately it looks like your query can be adjusted to add an additional condition with OR.  Then you have one query with one result set to loop through. You'll need to group your conditional sets with parenthesis.

```
$query = "
  SELECT SUM(KDV_Haric_Ciro) AS Ciro , Donem
  FROM general_Table
  Where (EczaneID = '".$pharmacy_id."') 
  AND (Yil = '".$dateYear."' OR Yil = '".$dateLastYear."')
  GROUP BY Donem";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query );

// Print out rows
$prefix = '';
echo "[\n";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
  echo $prefix . " {\n";
  echo '  "month": "' . $row["Donem"] . '",' . "\n";
  echo '  "ciro": ' . $row["Ciro"]. '' . "\n";
  echo '  "ciroLastYear": ' . $row["Ciro"]. '' . "\n";
  echo " }";
  $prefix = ",\n";
}
echo "\n]";
```

For more on this, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimization.html